# How can I make in elgg site the wire reply to open with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, elgg

In the wire in start.php I have this code for showing me the "reply" to the river:

```
    elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('register', 'menu:river', 'thewire_reply_river_menu_setup');


function thewire_reply_river_menu_setup($hook, $type, $return, $params) {
    $item = $params['item'];
    $object = $item->getObjectEntity();
    if ($item->subtype == 'thewire' && elgg_is_logged_in()) {
        $return[] = ElggMenuItem::factory(array(
            'name' => 'demyx_wire',
            'href' => elgg_normalize_url("thewire/reply/{$object->guid}"),
            'text' => 'Reply',
            'priority' => 90,
        ));
    }

    return $return;
}
```

How can I make the link opens in a popup? I try with "onclick="window.open", I also try with 'class'=>'elgg-lightbox' but no... If anyone can help for how it's possible to open the "href" in a popup window with or with out ajax (I'd prefer it with ajax) .

Thanks!